# OpenMPI на одном компьютере с многоядерным процессором

Tags: многопоточность, библиотеки

Добрый день.

Могу я использовать OpenMPI на одном компьютере, не на кластере, и получать при этом выигрыш в производительности?

Comment: Можете, но если есть выбор, лучше используйте OpenMP. Для систем с разделяемой памятью самое подходящее.

Comment: Да у меня просто курсач по этому делу :)

Comment: Тогда Бог в помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

конечно, если он многоядерный